# Move from Wp to Drupal without downtime

Tags: 7, migrations

If I have wordpress right now with a bit of content (on a linux VPS with apache) and I want to switch over to drupal with the least possible downtime what do you recommend? Is it possible to install drupal separately and then put the content in it and then make it active over the wordpress somehow? Sorry if this was a silly thought as I don't have experience with any of this.

Comment: What version? Drupal 7 can migrate from WP fairly easily. There is a WP to Drupal module as well as the migrate framework which is super simple to script the move.

Comment: I'm not really committed to the version of drupal. So I could consider version 7. This is the only option? What I said about installing it separately first, would it be more work than using this migrate framework?

Comment: That's how you would migrate. Install Drupal 7, then you provide the Wordpress XML dump or you can script it with the migrate framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've mentioned, you will want to install drupal 7 separately and try Wordpress Migrate.

https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate

It only needs the export of Wordpress which can be done in the Wordpress admin.

You will want to try this out first on your own machine, Acquia Dev Desktop will work for you. Read through some of the docs and walkthroughs on the migration. I've done it a few times, it's very quick and typically works fine.

https://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop

Once you are setup and established, you can migrate to Drupal 8.2.x-8.3.x without much trouble.

Comment: The main reason I suggest WP > 7 > 8 is because you can do an automatic migration for all 3... I am not sure if you can just go from WP to Drupal 8 without doing any coding, and the migration docs for 8 are not as complete as they are for 7.

Comment: Yep, still a ways to go for migrating WordPress directly to D8: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/wordpress_migrate?version=8.x